# Should I undelete this answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I came across an answer by @coleopterist to [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/why-was-a-10-year-old-kid-appointed-consul) that is up-voted, and otherwise appears to be a worthwhile addition to the site, but was deleted by owner two months after being posted. There are no other answers to the question.

Should I undelete this answer?

Or is it better to respect the wishes of the owner, even if the answer would be a positive addition to the site?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I don't mean to ignore the author's wishes, but it is a valuable answer.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I am hoping to get more input, including from @coleopterist, before making a moving forward.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens You could ask one of our mods (in chat, or via a flag), to superping (same as the regular ping, but it will force an inbox notification) coleopterist and point him to this discussion. I could do that myself, being a SE chat moderator, but I really don't want to use my mod powers for an issue on a site I'm not a mod.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Thank you, good idea. Given the season, I will assume for now that coleopterist is simply occupied, and wait until the New Year to do more.

Comment: "Yes. I don't meant[sic] to ignore the author's wishes, but it is a valuable answer." H.SE is governed by Community Commons, the author's only rights to their answer is one of attribution.

Comment: @user1873 - rights != etiquette :)

Comment: @DVK, sure, but the author should have known that they don't "own" their answer, and if they choose to delete it, SE doesn't have to keep it that way. I don't think this is a question of etiquette either.